# How can I optimize this function? c# scan text file for strings

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I'm writing a program to scan a text file for blocks of strings (lines) and output the blocks to a file when found
In my process class, the function proc() is taking an unusually long time to process a 6MB file.  On a previous program I wrote where I scan the text for only one specific type of string it took 5 seconds to process the same file.  Now I rewrote it to scan for the presence of different strings.  it is taking over 8 minutes which is a significant difference.  Does any one have any ideas how to optimize this function?

This is my RegEx

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex RegExp { get { return new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?s)(?-m)MSH.+?(?=[\r\n]([^A-Z0-9]|.{1,2}[^A-Z0-9])|$)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled); } }
```

.

```
 public static class TypeFactory
{
    public static List<IMessageType> GetTypeList()
    {
        List<IMessageType> types = new List<IMessageType>();
        types.AddRange(from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                       where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMessageType))
                       select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IMessageType);

        return types;
    }
}

public class process
{


    public void proc()
    {
        IOHandler.Read reader = new IOHandler.Read(new string[1] { @"C:\TEMP\DeIdentified\DId_RSLTXMIT.LOG" });

        List<IMessageType> types = MessageType.TypeFactory.GetTypeList();

        //TEST1
        IOHandler.Write.writeReport(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), "TEST", "v3test.txt", true);

        foreach (string file in reader.FileList)
        {
            using (FileStream readStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int charVal = 0;
                Int64 position = 0;
                StringBuilder fileFragment = new StringBuilder();
                string message = string.Empty;

                string current = string.Empty;
                string previous = string.Empty;

                int currentLength = 0;
                int previousLength = 0;

                bool found = false;

                do
                {
                    //string line = reader.ReturnLine(readStream, out charVal, ref position);
                    string line = reader.ReturnLine(readStream, out charVal);

                    for (int i = 0; i < types.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(line, types[i].BeginIndicator)) //found first line of a message type
                        {
                            found = true;
                            message += line;

                            do
                            {
                                previousLength = types[i].RegExp.Match(message).Length;

                                //keep adding lines until match length stops growing
                                //message += reader.ReturnLine(readStream, out charVal, ref position);
                                message += reader.ReturnLine(readStream, out charVal);
                                currentLength = types[i].RegExp.Match(message).Length;

                                if (currentLength == previousLength)
                                {
                                    //stop - message complete
                                    IOHandler.Write.writeReport(message, "TEST", "v3test.txt", true);

                                    //reset
                                    message = string.Empty;
                                    currentLength = 0;
                                    previousLength = 0;
                                    break;
                                }


                            } while (charVal != -1);



                            break;
                        }
                    }




                } while (charVal != -1);


                //END OF FILE CONDITION
                if (charVal == -1)
                {

                }

            }

        }
        IOHandler.Write.writeReport(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), "TEST", "v3test.txt", true);
    }
}
```

.

EDIT: I ran profiling wizard in VS2012 and I found most time was spent on RegEx.Match function

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: You could also implement a basic logger that puts a `timestamp` at each spot to find the bottleneck if the profiler doesn't help.

Comment: When I saw the `StringBuilder` I had high hopes that you were going to use it to *build the string*, then I saw `message += line;` :(

Comment: I tried to use StringBuilder to construct the string but it had no effect on the performance in this way I am using it, so I stuck with just using the string.  which i kind of suspected because i have to keep converting the StringBuilder ToString() each time to evaluate it.

Comment: It would probably be good to know what your regex patterns look like. You could be experiencing ["catastrophic backtracking"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some thoughts:

- RegEx matching is not the most efficient way to do a substring search, and you are performing the match check once per "type" of match.  Have a look at efficient substring matching algorithms such as [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) if you need to match literal substrings rather than patterns.
- If you must use RegEx, consider [using compiled expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx).
- Use a BufferedStream to improve IO performance.  Probably marginal for a 6MB file, but it only costs a line of code.
- Use a profiler to be sure exactly where time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

High level ideas:

1. Use Regex.Matches to find all matches at once instead of one by one. Probably the main performance hit
2. Pre-build the search pattern to include multiple messages at once. You can use Regex OR.